# load balancing wso2 IS

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, wso2-identity-server

wso2 maintains user token information in it's internal database.  This would be a problem when a access token is sent to another wso2 IS for validating authentication, i.e when wso2 IS is behind a load balancer.

Any idea where/how to configure wso2 IS to maintain the user authorization/authentication tokens in a central database?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a centralized DB for both IS nodes. What you have to do is change the master-datasource.xml inside `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/datasources` to point to the correct DB. And it is not recommended to use the given internal H2 DB in production.